# Elegant way to translate set of weighted sums to python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Given a set of terms `||(p_i' - sum{w_ji*(R_j*p_i+v_j)})||^2`, where `||...||^2` denotes the squared norm, I want to efficiently set up an array (or a list) in Python filled with these terms. `p_i'`, `p_i`, `v_j` are three-dimensional vectors, and `R_j` is a 3x3 matrix.

I've already tried this but I don't know how to incorporate the sum over `j`.

```
new_points = r_mesh.points() # p', return Nx3 array
old_points = avg_mesh.points() # p
n_joints = 3
rv = np.arange(n_joints * 15) # R_j and v_j are stored in rv
weights = np.random.rand(n_joints, len(new_points)) # w

func = [[np.linalg.norm(
        new_points[i] - (weights[j, i] * ((np.array(rv[j * 15:j * 15 + 9]).reshape(3, 3) @ old_points[i]) + np.array(
            rv[j * 9 + 9: j * 9 + 12])))) for j in range(n_joints)] for i in range(len(new_points))]
```

To make things clearer here is the original equation that I transformed into a non-linear function as to feed it to the Levenberg-Marquardt method.

[image: Imgur]

EDIT: I'm sorry, before, there was a wrong image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest ("auto pilot", no actual thinking required) method would be `np.einsum`:

```
# set up example:
n_i, n_j = 20, 30

p = np.random.random((n_i, 3))
pp = np.random.random((n_i, 3))
R = np.random.random((n_j, 3, 3))
w = np.random.random((n_j, n_i))
v = np.random.random((n_j, 3))

# now just tell einsum which index is where and let it 
# do its magic

# R_j p_i
Rp = np.einsum('jkl,il', R,p)
# by Einstein convention this will sum over l,
# so Rp has indices ijk

# w_ji (Rp_ij + v_j)
wRpv = np.einsum('ji,ijk->ik', w,Rp+v)
# pure Einstein convention would sum over i and j,
# we  override this by passing explicit output indices       
# ik to keep i alive

# squared norm
d = pp - wRpv
result = np.einsum('ik,ik', d,d)
```